# What are these orphan IE windows that appear sometimes when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, internet-explorer, windows-7

I use Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. Occasionally (more than once a day), when I launch the debugger via F5 to debug an ASP.NET website a blank Internet Explorer window opens and it hangs.

I can stop the debugger, but the IE window doesn't go away. When I try to debug again, a new IE window opens and I can debug in that window just fine.

But the original IE window never goes away, even when quitting Visual Studio. I've even had 2 of them on my desktop at once. In fact the only way to get rid of it is to logout or restart the system.

Anybody experienced this? Is there some problem that needs fixing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm experiencing the exact same behavior -orphan instances of iexplore.exe left in memory when I stop debugging

Comment: In Win2k3 I get the same thing, except IE _does_ close when you stop the debugger.